# "git submodule foreach" syntax error in Jenkins pipeline, but works on command line?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I can execute the following on a command line, where I just want to checkout a `feature/*` branch, and if the sub module does not have it, I want to checkout `master`.

```
$ git submodule foreach 'git checkout feature/test-new-scripts || git checkout master'
```

However, if I execute the same command in a Jenkins pipeline, I get a syntax error.

```
sh """
  git submodule foreach \\'git checkout feature/test-new-scripts || git checkout master\\'
"""
```

I get the following error

```
+ git submodule foreach "git checkout feature/test-new-scripts
Entering 'module1'
"git: 1: "git: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
fatal: run_command returned non-zero status for module1
.
+ git checkout master"
error: pathspec 'master"' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

I've tried the following syntax, where I just changed the single quotes (`'...'`) in the command itself to double quotes (`"..."`), to no avail

```
sh """
  git submodule foreach \\"git checkout feature/test-new-scripts || git checkout master\\"
"""
```

What is the correct syntax do accomplish what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message indicates this is indeed an issue with Groovy string casting in the `sh` step method parameter. We can clean this up a bit to assist:

```
sh(label: 'Git Submodule Checkout', script: "git submodule foreach 'git checkout feature/test-new-scripts || git checkout master'")
```

It may also be possible to achieve this with the [GitSCM](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/params/gitscm/) class as well by the way.

Comment: Thank you, I will try both solutions and will provide feedback.

Comment: This `sh(...)` trick worked like a charm. Thanks!